# How to get the array of pixel values for an image in java using getRGB

Tags: java, pixel

I'm new to image processing in java. Actually what I'm trying to do is to save all the pixel values of an image into an array `rgbArray[]`, and the problem is that I'm getting the same values in all the indexes of an array i.e. all the indexes of the array have the same value. A part of code is given below:

```
int[] rgbArray=new int[w*h];     // Array to store the Pixel values
BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
buffer.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, rgbArray, 0, w );
for(int i=0;i<w*h;i++)
 {
  System.out.println("rgbArray["+i+"] = "+ rgbArray[i]);
 }
```

The output which i'm getting is `-16777216` for all indexes in `rgbArray`. How is it possible to have the same value for each and every pixel of the image? And how do I get the correct pixel value??

Comment: I can't see anywhere where you put an image in the buffered image. Created like that, it's totally empty, so the values are all the same

Comment: Thax for the help but can you please guide me how to put an image in the buffered image and which part of code is missing??

Comment: Thax I got it.. I did't gave the value to the buffered image...thax alot.. :) Bt i'll be in need of some more help as i'm wrking on image processing software.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not provide any values for the BufferedImage, every pixel defaults to alpha = 255, red = 0, green = 0, and blue = 0;  Put all of those into 1 int and you get -16777216.  I got this from:

```
int val = buffer.getRGB(5, 23);
int a = (0xff000000 & val) >>> 24;
int r = (0x00ff0000 & val) >> 16;
int g = (0x0000ff00 & val) >> 8;
int b = (0x000000ff & val);
System.out.println("a " + a + " r " + r + " g " + g + " b " + b);
```

Which produces a 255 r 0 g 0 b 0.

Comment: Thax for the help.. And yes you are right, m getting the same values as you wrote above.. Can u please guide me how to put an image in the buffered image which part of code is missing??

Comment: Thax I got it.. I did't give the value to the buffered image...thax alot.. :) Bt i'll be in need of some more help as i'm wrking on image processing software.. :)