# BufferedImage setRGB strange result

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage

I've try to rotate an Image in Java using `setRGB` and `BufferedImage`, but I get a strange result. Has anyone any idea why?

```
 BufferedImage pic1 = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/Input-1.bmp"));
    int width  = pic1.getWidth(null);
    int height = pic1.getHeight(null);

    double angle = Math.toRadians(90);
    double sin = Math.sin(angle);
    double cos = Math.cos(angle);
    double x0 = 0.5 * (width  - 1);     // point to rotate about
    double y0 = 0.5 * (height - 1);     // center of image

    BufferedImage pic2 = pic1;

    // rotation
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            double a = x - x0;
            double b = y - y0;
            int xx = (int) (+a * cos - b * sin + x0);
            int yy = (int) (+a * sin + b * cos + y0);

            if (xx >= 0 && xx < width && yy >= 0 && yy < height) {
                pic2.setRGB(x, y, pic1.getRGB(xx, yy));
            }
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(pic2, "bmp", new File("Images/Output2.bmp"));
```

In the **LEFT** side is the original picture and in the **RIGHT** side it's my result. Have anyone any idea how can I fix it? 
[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can't rotate an image in place.  You make another separate rotated image.  If you're going to rotate an image 90 degrees, you don't have to do the rotate math.  Just copy the x coordinate to the new y coordinate, and the y coordinate to the new x coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same image as input and output:

BufferedImage pic2 = pic1;

You must create another image for pic2 and then do the rotation, copying pixels from Image1 to Image2.

Note, however, that using getRGB and setRGB it terribly slow. Its 100 times faster if you manipulate the pixels directly.

Comment: Thanks  I didn't notice this error :D now it works. and about the setRBG and getRGB... I know they are so slow.... but I don't know how to convert a image into something like pixels[ ][ ]. I've search every where on internet and all what I've see it's how to get an array 1D from an image, I mean something like pixels[ ]. But I need an 2D array like pixels[ ][ ] and I had no idea how to obtain it.... Can you help me with and with this please? :D

Comment: In this one you create an image with the pixels:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856569/how-to-get-the-array-of-pixel-values-for-an-image-in-java-using-getrgb